# SQL Query in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene

Hey I'm new to Elasticsearch and want to "translate" this SQL query :

```
SELECT"*" FROM Results WHERE "Id"=2 AND Number IN (25,27, 29) AND Date BETWEEN Date1 AND Date 2 ORDER BY Date LIMIT 20
```

**EDIT:** By "translate" I mean i want to convert the SQL statement to an elaticsearch query.
I tried that but the elasticsearch query below isn't working yet :(

I wanted to do this using filters and I've got so far:

```
{
"filtered": {
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "date": {
                        "gt": "2008-01-01",
                        "lt": "2014-01-01"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "Id": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "number": [
                        25,
                        27,
                        29
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
             "limit": {
                    "value": 20
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I read the docs and tried examples, made simple queries, I hope somebody can help me with this!

Comment: Note: you also can check if your SQL query runs directly with your Elasticsearch instance, since the [Elasticsearch 6.3 release, now (June 2018) comes with native SQL support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50889538/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search looks good - which part isn't working?

I would use [size](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) to limit the number of results returned (instead of limit which limits the number of documents checked). 
I've also added a [sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html).

The drawback with using filter is that it doesn't do any scoring - possibly you should move the `Number IN (25,27, 29)` section to a query and then results with more matches will score higher?
The other fields look suitable for a filter though (i.e. a binary match / didn't match).

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/results/_search?pretty' -d '{
   "size" : 20,
   "sort" : [{"number" : {"order" : "desc"}}],
   "filter": {
      "and": [
        {
            "range": {
                "date": {
                    "gt": "2008-01-01",
                    "lt": "2014-01-01"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "Id": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "terms": {
                "number": [
                    25,
                    27,
                    29
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}'
```

Comment: With your help it kinda works now, when I remove the "date" in my sort part..otherwise I get `[No mapping found for [date] in order to sort on]`  I sorted on DATE instaed of NUMBER

Comment: Glad it's working for you, can you accept one of the answers?