# Combining Filters in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

This is the basic **SQL query** which I want to convert into **elasticsearch** query,

```
SELECT product
FROM   products
WHERE  (price = 200 OR ID = "101")
  AND  (price != 300)
```

This is a **query in elasticsearch** that I have tried:

```
GET /my_store/my_product_items/_search

{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 { "term" : {"price" : 200}}, 
                 { "term" : {"productID" : "101"}} 
              ],
              "must_not" : {
                 "term" : {"price" : 300} 
              }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But it didn't give the same output as per SQL query. Do support.

TIA. :)

Comment: Note: you also can check out the [Elasticsearch 6.3 release, now (June 2018) with native SQL support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50889538/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good start! You simply need to change `must` with `should` and you're good:

```
GET /my_store/my_product_items/_search

{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "minimum_should_match": 1,         <--- add this
              "should" : [                       <--- change this
                 { "term" : {"price" : 200}}, 
                 { "term" : {"productID" : "101"}} 
              ],
              "must_not" : {
                 "term" : {"price" : 300} 
              }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What "minimum_should_match" is indicate ?

Comment: That at least one clause of the `should` clauses should match, which is exactly what an `OR` is all about