# How to parse the where clause in java into elastic query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am getting below where clause from client and I want to convert that into elastic search understandable format.

I want to know is there any library available to parse such kind of where clause and convert into ELK search format.

```
where keywords~'some thning here' AND Status='LIVE' AND ( name='RSP,RFP' OR (user='teacher' AND source='my uploads')) AND (version='1' OR version!=0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic conversion of SQL query to ElasticSearch Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375086/automatic-conversion-of-sql-query-to-elasticsearch-query)

Comment: @andrewjames  no , that does not help me , but thanks.

Comment: OK - understood. Just a suggestion - It might be helpful to clarify (by editing your question) why none of the suggestions & links in the other question can help you.